# webdev - how do I make a progress bar using a texture to determine progress using either html, css, or js

Tags: javascript, html, css, graphics

Motive: I want to use uncommon shapes for interactive web animations. For example, I have this texture/gradient:

[image: example progress texture]

As the value for this progress icon reaches its maximum (ie 255), I want the icon to be filled up. For example, by setting the opacity of all pixels with a lower luminosity than the current / max value * max luminosity. It is derivative of similar logic in the below image, which was used in Unreal 4.

[image]

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tqgNDZ19hE

Is there a way to translate this sort of logic to a web application?